# Using Mapper.Map inside query linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have error in this line :

```
var patientDto = patientsQuery.ToList().Select(<b>Mapper.Map<Patient, PatientDto></b>);
```

How can i resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Also read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Knowing how to ask is the key to get an answer

Comment: Mapper.Map<Patient, PatientDto> on red line error how can i resolve this issue

Comment: What does the actual error say?

Comment: An object reference is required for the property, method or non-static field 'Mapper.Map <Patient, PatientDto> (Patient)'

Comment: Which version of automapper are you using?

Comment: version 9.0.0.0;version  runtime v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

So automapper since version `9.0` removed the static invocation of the `Map` function. Now you'll need to get the mapper instance.

If you don't use dependency injection you can create a wrapper class with static members to use

```cs
public static class StaticMapper
{
    public static void Initialize(MapperConfiguration config)
    {
        Mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }

    public static IMapper Mapper { get; private set; }
}
```

Then after you configure the mapper you can init the static class

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Patient, PatientDto>());
StaticMapper.Initialize(config);
```

And finally call it when you need it

```cs
var patientDto = patientsQuery.ToList().Select(StaticMapper.Mapper.Map<Patient, PatientDto>);
```

Hope it helps